# Puppet Windows Agent Certificate

Tags: puppet

I have puppet master on RHEL 6 and agent on Windows. 
IT is showing up properly in the console Web, however it is not downloading new catalogue, due to CA error. 
I did renew on client, but the master does not show up the windows cert at all for accepting.

Comment: What is the current console output on the agent when running `puppet agent --test`?

Comment: It says exiting waiting for CA certificate. 
Have deleted the Ssl folder under puppet from my home directory under Windows and rerun the command to generate the keys afresh. Still the same error. 
On the puppet master have run the command to list the CA, but it does not list any. 

Have checked all the port connectivity, all are fine. 
clueless now to find the issue.

Comment: You can try inspecting the output of `puppet agent -tdv`. If this doesn't help, next big gun is to run a master process with debugging output as well (master side of course), then initiating the agent run and inspect the master output (`puppet master --no-daemonize -dv` while the regular master is not running).

Comment: Me getting, could not retrieve catalog from remote server :error 400 on server :could not find class my website for (node name) on (node name).

Comment: That cannot be the message - class names cannot contain spaces. Either way, it would appear that your SSL issues are solved now, yes? If that is the case, please close this question. You can open a new one for the new issue, but I believe that it should not be hard to debug that one yourself. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks, the Ssl is resolved.

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be the agent has a newer certificate and the master will only accept one certificate per machine (based on fqdn or fully qualified domain name). What you need to do is remove the certificate from the master so that it will accept the new request from the machine.

Alternatively you should also make sure you are in an elevated process always when running Puppet (unless you are in advanced scenarios where you are using lower privileges and know all the ins and outs of what that entails on Windows). The reason? Puppet home for elevated processes is in `C:\ProgramData\PuppetLabs\Puppet`, for non-elevated it is in `~/.puppet` (which is usually `C:\Users\username\.puppet`). A certificate request for each machine can only be accepted once, but a non-elevated process won't see the one in ProgramData and will try unsuccessfully to request another.

Also make sure that the firewall on the Windows machine is not preventing it from accessing the Puppet Server, the port is usually 8140. This can cause SSL issues in reaching the master.

Comment: It appears the question was resolved in comments but I wanted to add an answer for others who may happen upon this question.